# Using Twitter Bootstrap in ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to write my first ASP.NET website and I really want to use the Twitter Bootstrap but I'm failing at the first hurdle.

I downloaded the Zip file from [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), unzipped it and added the files to my solution and the following lines to my _LAyout.cshtml file:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Context/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is a screenshot showing the above files in my solution:

[image: CSS files]
[image: Scripts]

I am trying to create a menu bar across the top with this code which was taken from [this turorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/stepping-out-with-bootstrap-from-twitter/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Context/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="topbar">
        <div class="fill">
            <div class="container">
                <h3>Present Ideas</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Blog</li>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>Help</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav secondary-nav">
                    <li class="menu">
                        <a href="#" class="menu">Account Settings</a>
                        <ul class="menu-dropdown">
                            <li>Login</li>
                            <li>Register</li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li>Logout</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I get, instead of the horizontal bar is this:

[image: Result - vertical bar instead of horizontal]

I would appreciate any help to get me started with what promises to be, an excellent framework.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using Twitter Bootstrap 2.0, but the tutorial was written for Twitter Bootstrap 1.0, there has been quite a few changes to the markup you need to use to get the desired look.

It explains some of the changes to the navbar component in the [changelog](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v2.0.0), there are also some basic examples of how it is done now:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html#examples

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar

Also (unrelated to the question), you're including *both* the minified version and the standard version of the css/js, you only need to include one of each.

Comment: Thanks very much!  That solved my issue and also highlighted the really rather useful documentation on Github that I'd failed to spot.