# Does twitter bootstrap work with ASP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic, twitter-bootstrap

I am used to working with ASP web apps and creating .aspx pages. I don't know PHP really and I have worked a while with C# and ASP. I really like bootstrap so far and designing with it in HTML looks great and seems to work great. However, I am concerned that somehow this won't transfer over to ASP.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243636/using-twitter-bootstrap-in-asp-net-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter's bootstrap is used for presentation and doesn't have to do anything with any programming language. You can use the bootstrap in any project using any language provided that you include the `bootstrap.css` stylesheet and use the CSS classes included accordingly, so there should be no concerns over whether the bootstrap will "transfer over to ASP" or any other language.

Comment: I appreciate the comment. I was an idiot (literally... embarrassing). I forgot to include <form id="form" runat="server"> from the master page. Oops. Thanks for the respond though.

Answer (score 5):

Twitter Bootstrap is just a bunch of CSS/JS files. So it works with every web technology out there.

Another thing is that ASP.NET (at least, old one, before MVC) is relying heavily on server controls. So it could be problematic to apply twitter stylesheets and behaviour to asp.net server controls. I don't know if it got any better in modern asp.net.

As long as you use regular HTML markup to define your UI and some Javascript to bring life to it, you should be fine.

Comment: So instead of using <asp:Button /> I should still use the input button?

Comment: @Tom: at least, input button is known to work. But it won't automatically postback to the server.

Comment: SO there is no way to use ASP.NET server controls with bootstrap? I keep getting errors when using them.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the Bootstrap CSS classes to ASP.NET controls using the CssClass parameter:

```
<asp:Button id="btnExample" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Example" />
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include a brief explanation of why your code would work rather then code-only answers.